# Three.js - How to link/add a light to the camera since r69?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Since r69 this pattern is no longer supported [(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653241/three-js-pointlight-changes-from-r-67-to-r-68?answertab=active#tab-top) :

```
directionalLight.position = camera.position;
```

So I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920101/threejs-r69-trackball-controls-camera-and-directional-light?answertab=active#tab-top) :

```
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 ); 
camera.add( pointLight );
```

But the light doesn't work (black out), and it's the same thing with a `DirectionalLight`

What could be the problem ?

---

Note : of course if I do this the light doesn't follow the camera :

```
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
directionalLight.position.set( camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z );
scene.add( directionalLight );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a light as a child of the camera, you need to add the camera to the scene, so the light will be part of the scene graph.

```
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff ); 
camera.add( pointLight );
scene.add( camera );
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Ok thanks ! But inversely if you don't add a light you don't need to ... I do not quite understand the logic, in fact I thought that the camera was added by the controls ...

Comment: It used to be required that the camera be added to the scene. It is no longer a requirement. The reason: there can be multiple scenes, and an object can have only one parent.

Comment: I know it's a few years later, but apparently camera must still be added to scene for its PointLight to be functional.

Comment: @taranaki The camera must only be added to the scene if it has a child object.